# Cancellable file download

Tags: ios, objective-c, download

I have code like this:

```
- (void)downloadFile:(void (^)(BOOL success))callback {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/largefile.bin"];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            callback(YES);
    });
}
```

Also I have progress dialog that is created and shown before calling this method and then will be hidden after callback. I need somehow to be able to cancel file download. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to use NSURLConnection and NSURLConnectionDelegate. Create a class to do all your downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is based on @Fogmeister comment.

`Downloader.h`:

```
@interface Downloader : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

- (void) download:(NSURL *)url;
- (void) cancel;

@end
```

`Downloader.m`:

```
@implementation Downloader {
    NSMutableData * receivedData;
    NSURLConnection * urlConnection;
}

- (void) download:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];

    urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}

- (void) cancel
{
    if (urlConnection != nil) {
        [urlConnection cancel];
        urlConnection = nil;
    }
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    urlConnection = nil;
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    urlConnection = nil;
    // process receivedData
}
```